# How to intentionally break rar archive (make it unreadable)?

Tags: windows, archive, corrupt, rar

I want to intentionally break **rar** archive for testing purposes.
I was trying to copy archive in the middle or archiving process but it is impossible due to read lock (I use windows 7).

**How to do that?**

Comment: Q: If you want a "bogus .rar" file, why not just take some arbitrary text file, copy it to "test.rar" and run your .rar test.  Q: If you want a .rar file that's corrupt in the middle, why not use a binary editor like [hexedit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hexedit/)?  Q: What does a "file in use" runtime error have to do with "intentionally breaking a .rar for testing purposes"???

Comment: I would rename a random file to .rar

Comment: @paulsm4 I got script that download rar files. Sometimes downloading is timeouted and i got corrupted archive. That archives could be PARTIALLY extracted.

Comment: Instead, try killing the archive process mid-way through building the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think opening with editor and deleting some chunks of the gibberish code should work. However, there would still be trouble with the read-lock.

I tested it with a .zip file. After the first delete (first ~10 lines) it was still readable by 7-Zip, after deleting some more lines it was corrupted and Windows Explorer nor 7-Zip was able to open it.

Comment: I opened rar with text editor and delete some text in it. Unfortunately this only works if archive size is small. Some parts of files are still extractable - that is what I want. Thx!

Comment: @Mr.Che I guess deleting larger chunks would make it completely unreadable. If someone knows the specification of rar files, he could delete something like the index of the file rendering it completely useless.